# Microsoft Hosted Exchange: Possible to outsource single mail account?

Tags: exchange, postfix, smtp

I have a customer who polls e-mail for a number of accounts in domain *example.com* via POP. Now they have a VIP user *boss@example.com* who wants to use Microsoft Hosted Exchange on his mobile phone.

Unfortunately the descriptions of Hosted Exchange aren't too detailed and in heavy Microsoft lingo. My question is: Can it be configured so that it handles mail for this single user, while all other mail accounts remain on the POP server?

One approach for inbound mail would be to buy Hosted Exchange for a dedicated domain, such as *exchange.example.com* and reroute *boss@example.com* to *boss@exchange.example.com*.

Which leaves outbound mail: Can Hosted Exchange be configured to relay mail through my mail relay where I can rewrite the sender *boss@exchange.example.com* to *boss@example.com*? Or can it forge the sender address on outbound mail altogether, without relaying through my server? (SPF records are not an issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Can it be configured so that it handles mail for this single user, while all other mail accounts remain on the POP server?"**

Yes, Exchange can be used to host a single account where the mail flow for the user is redirected from the another (POP) server. The user would just access the Exchange configuration versus the POP server.

**"Can Hosted Exchange be configured to relay mail through my mail relay where I can rewrite the sender boss@exchange.example.com to boss@example.com?"**

Yes, Exchange can be configured to relay through the existing servers (keeping spam management simpler/same) as well as present *boss@example.com* as the return address.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide a few more words on how outbound mail works? Does this involve my subdomain approach and set a reply-to header, or what is exactly happening?

Comment: You should not need to modify the "reply-to" as the Exchange address space can be set to match the domain of the original forwarding (POP) server. Everything, incoming and outgoing, can route through the original (POP) infrastructure.